# Why my script doesnt work?

Tags: shell-script

I wrote this script for some web scraping, but it isn't working.

I'm a beginner, so I have no idea, also because it isn't showing errors.

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@LiliSousa/web-scraping-with-bash-690e4ee7f98d) article.

```
#!/bin/bash

n="1"
rm -f tmp_file extractData.csv
# colunas do arquivo CSV
echo "nome;local;acervo" > livrariasevsp.csv
while [ $n -lt 10 ]
do
    # exec o curl e salva no arquivo temporario
    curl "https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/garimpepor/sebos-e-livreiros/sp?livraria=$n" > tmp_file
    # contador "nome"
    n=$[$n+1]
    # get nome
    nome=$(cat tmp_file |grep "class=\"sebo-nome\"" | cut -d'>' -f4 | cut -d'<' -f1)
    # get local
    local=$(cat tmp_file |grep "class=\"js-sebo-local\"" | grep span | cut -d'>' -f4 | cut -d'<' -f1)
    # get acervo
    acervo=$(cat tmp_file |grep "class=\"js-sebo-acervo\"" | grep span | cut -d'>' -f4 | cut -d'<' -f1)
    # escreve os dados das livrarias no arquivo CSV
    echo "$nome;$local;$acervo" >> livrariasevsp.csv
done
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what is it doing?

Comment: It should take the name of the bookstores on the URL, the city under the name and the number of books. Take a look at the URL and you will see. As a result, I'm just getting the .csv file with the columns, but no data.

Comment: I corrected the line `rm -f tmp_file extractData.csv` with `rm -f tmp_file livrariasevsp.csv`.

Comment: `class="sebo-nome"` and `class="js-sebo-local"` don't exist within that page.  `class="js-sebo-acervo"` exists several times.

Comment: On a way I can understand, which classes should I use to grab the information of the first bookstore: "1000 Livros" ; "São Paulo, SP" ; "13.370" ? Because when I inspect these elements, I see the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually advocate parsing HTML using regular expressions. However

```
awk -F'[<>]' '
  BEGIN {print "nome;local;acervo"}
  $2 ~ /^h2 .*-titulo/ {title = $3}
  $2 ~ /^span .*-local/ {city = $3}
  $2 ~ /^span .* nlivros=/ {printf "\"%s\";\"%s\";%d\n", title, city, $3}
' tmp_file > livrariasevsp.csv
```

Note, the `$[...]` form of arithmetic expansion is undocumented. Use `$((...))` instead. However, you don't actually need to do that. Try this:

```
{
    echo "nome;local;acervo"
    for n in {1..9}; do
        url="https://www.estantevirtual.com.br/garimpepor/sebos-e-livreiros/sp?livraria=$n"
        awk -F'[<>]' '
            $2 ~ /^h2 .*-titulo/ {title = $3}
            $2 ~ /^span .*-local/ {city = $3}
            $2 ~ /^span .* nlivros=/ {
                printf "\"%s\";\"%s\";%d\n", title, city, $3
            }
        ' <( curl --silent "$url" )
    done 
} > livrariasevsp.csv
```

Comment: Let the downvoting commence...

Comment: Although I prefer the answer using curl, so I can understand better, the code worked pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: This does use curl, see the line above "done"

Comment: I meant the way I was doing, to understand why my code didn't work.

Comment: The main fatal flaws:

Comment: 1. the strings `class=\"sebo-nome\"` does not appear in the HTML. The class
attribute for the book title *contains* the "sebo-nome" class, but the
regular expression you use in the grep command will find no lines. Similar
problem to find the city and the number of books.

Comment: 2. The way you try to combine the `$nome` `$local` and `$acervo` values is
wrong. You're not taking elements from each list to form records of a CSV,
you are just joining big blobs of text with a couple of semicolons.

Comment: 3. and mainly, you don't parse HTML with regular expressions, for robustness you must use an HTML parser.